# Update form not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 files, 1) form 2) update file

This is the update form update.php:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="username"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="datasename"; // Database name
$tbl_name="data"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>


<div align="center"><img src="http://www.multihunters.co.uk/images/tf_ideal/blue/misc/logo.png" width="400" height="125">

</div>
<div align="center">
  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
        <td>
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center"><strong>Citizen ID</strong></td>
              <td align="center"><strong>Citizen Name</strong></td>
              <td align="center"><strong>Citizenship</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center">
                <input name="citid" type="text" id="citid" value="<? echo $rows['citid']; ?>">
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <input name="citname" type="text" id="citname" value="<? echo $rows['citname']; ?>" size="15">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input name="citizenship" type="text" id="citizenship" value="<? echo $rows['citizenship']; ?>" size="15">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
                <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();

?>
```

This is the my action form update_ac.php:

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="username"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="database"; // Database name
$tbl_name="data"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET citid='$citid', citname='$citname', citizenship='$citizenship' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='http://www.multihunters.co.uk/citizens_permlist.php'>View result</a>";
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

The message Successful appears but when I check to see if the data has been updated nothing has changed, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You did not define `$citid`, `$citname`, `$citizenship` and `$id`. You must fetch it from `$_POST`, escape it, then put it in the query.

Also, please stop using `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli` or PDO Extension.

Comment: thank you, i defined all as suggested above and now works, the only thing i didnt change is to mysqli as i don't know how to convert the above to that

Comment: @SimonHind Both APIs would require you to learn things from scratch again. For PDO, the tutorial I can find is here: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers but I can't seem to find a MySQLi for `mysql_*` developers tutorial. Might want to just learn all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code to

```
$citid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['citid']);
$citname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['citname']);
$citizenship = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['citizenship']);

$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET citid='$citid', citname='$citname', citizenship='$citizenship' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

**Note**

> PHP functions that start with `mysql_` have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions instead.

Comment: Might want to add mysql_real_escape_string in there.

Comment: @TimothyChoi yah you are right, but the better way is to use PDO and prepare statements

Comment: i know have it working on MYSQLi, i havent learnt PDO before which is something new to me, i suppose its about time i try coding usind PDO, if i find it easier than MYSQLi i might switch over